# Groovy Map in Map value retrieval

Tags: groovy

I am somewhat new to Groovy and am struggling with a Map of Maps issue.

Assuming I have a Groovy map defined as follows - each map entry consists of Brand, Weight and Charge:

// Each Map represents Brand, Weight, Charge

```
def crankcase = [
    ["GM", 22, 37],
    ["Ford", 221, 400],
    ["Dodge", 66, 150]
]
```

I am looking for the best way to be able to retrieve a given map entry based on Brand ( *GM, Ford or Dodge* ) and the associated Weight and Charge for that Brand.

I will be doing lookups constantly so I assume the solution she be performant.

Comment: First - in your example it's not a map. https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps

Comment: What dagget said. You have defined a list containing three other lists. No maps involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you are showing is **not** a map of maps - it is an
*vector of vectors* (list of lists, array of arrays, ...).  The
difference is, that maps would have a key for each value before the
value, separated with a `:`.  E.g. `[brand:GM, weight:22, charge:37]` is
a map.

You first would have to turn that into an vector of maps.  E.g.

```
def crankcase = [
    ["GM", 22, 37],
    ["Ford", 221, 400],
    ["Dodge", 66, 150]
]

def map = crankcase.collect{ [["brand", "weight", "charge"], it].transpose().collectEntries() }

println map
// → [[brand:GM, weight:22, charge:37], 
//    [brand:Ford, weight:221, charge:400], 
//    [brand:Dodge, weight:66, charge:150]]
```

And then you could e.g. group that by brand, so you get a map of brands
to vector of cases.

```
def casesByBrand = map.groupBy{ it.brand }

println casesByBrand

// → [GM:[[brand:GM, weight:22, charge:37]], 
//    Ford:[[brand:Ford, weight:221, charge:400]], 
//    Dodge:[[brand:Dodge, weight:66, charge:150]]]
```

Comment: Thank you ...perfect ...yes, I mislabeled Lists as Maps :=( ...I am relatively new to Groovy